# grep the files that contain specific word and don't contain those words

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I need to use grep command to get all the files that contain a [form] word,
and don't contain a [head] or [cfGenerate] words at the same time.

Comment: you could use `awk` instead... or pipe the output of grep for further processing (use -v to ignore lines).. or use PCRE if available..

Comment: to help you better, please add sample lines with expected output that would help in testing the answers... and add your current attempt..

Comment: Could you extend your question with a few sample files, indicating which ones should be included and which ones shouldn't? Ideally, you'd also show what you've tried so far and how it failed.

Comment: grep "form" -r -l -i  --include "*.cfm"  "C:\Test" | grep -E -v "head|cfGenerate" > c:\test\output2.txt , it is not working

Comment: I have 1.txt , 2.txt, ....., 1000.txt, -> I need to get the files that has [form] object and doesn't have [header] word

Comment: You should [edit] the question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score -1):

GNU grep with PCRE :

```
grep -P '^(?!.*head)(?!.*cfGenerate).*form'
```

negative lookaheads can be combined to make the match fail if any unwanted pattern occurs.